# How to write a query that filters on multiple conditions?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to get the product and amount info for Alex (as in attached). However, if Alex has got any product with the amount showing as zero shouldn't be picked up.

What query or formula should I go with on g-sheets?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use FILTER function with 2 conditions

Speaking english:
Show column with products and numbers
Column with numbers is not 0
Column with names is Alex

[image]

```
=filter(C2:D,B2:B=F2,D2:D<>0)
```

You can also do it using QUERY formula:

```
=query(B2:D,"select C,D where B = '"&F2&"' and D <> 0")
```

F2 is a cell where you put name